# Como abrir um form atrás de um form já aberto Delphi

Tags: delphi, tela, forms

Como abri uma `form` atrás de um outro `form` já aberto? Esse `form` que está aberto tem um tempo para fechar, quando fechar, preciso que o segundo `form` esteja aberto de forma *modal*.

Answer (score 0):

abra normalmente e use o comando SendToBack para enviar para trás

```
 form.show; 
 form.SendToBack;
```

Comment: valeu pela dica, só que quando fecha o form que esta na frente ele esta indo para traz de tela principal o segundo form

Comment: pode fazer tratamentos para corrigir, tenta usar o BringToFront no onClose

Answer (score -1):

Utilize a propriedade PopupMode e PopupParent dos formulários.

**Considere 3 Formulários**:
FormPrincipal é o formulário principal;
FormBackend é o formulário que deverá ser `Modal` e ficar por trás do FormCadastro;
FormCadastro é o formulário que aciona `FormBackend`, mas que deve ficar acima desse `FormBackend`;

Considere que a ordem de chamada dos formulários será:
FormPrincipal -> FormCadastro -> FormBackend

Considere que a ordem de apresentação dos formulários deve ser:
1 FormCadastro
2 FormBackend
3 FormPrincipal

Utilize as propriedades `PopupParent` e `PopupMode` para resolver a ordem das janelas.

Segue tradução de trecho da documentação oficial:

> A propriedade *PopupMode* controla como o formulário de nível superior
> se comporta em relação ao estilo *WS_POPUP* do Windows. Uma janela que
> possui o estilo *WS_POPUP* está sempre acima de seu "proprietário" na
> ordem Z. Você pode usar a propriedade *PopupMode* em conjunto com a
> propriedade *PopupParent* para evitar a aparência de um aplicativo
> travado causado por um diálogo modal aparecendo atrás de outro
> formulário na tela.

Leia mais na documentação oficial: http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/delphiAndcpp2009/HelpUpdate2/EN/html/delphivclwin32/Forms_TForm_PopupMode.html

**Propriedade alterada em FormBackend:**

```
PopupMode := pmExplicit;   
PopupParent := FormPrincipal;
```

**Propriedade alterada em FormCadastro:**

```
PopupMode := pmExplicit;
```

**Procedure alterando ordem pelo PopupParent:**

```
procedure TFormCadastro.butAtivarBackendClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
   FormCadastro.PopupParent :=  FormBackend;
   FormBackend.PopupMode:=pmAuto;
   FormBackend.ShowModal;
end;
```

**Projeto de teste:** [Projeto teste PopupParent](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1hQoDXp-GFvkjwXKp2mFRFjVpft9gy5xU/view?usp=sharing)